# Built java class not representing changes

Tags: java, cognos-bi

Warning: I am no Java nor Eclipse expert!

I have inherited a Java project in Eclipse. I have made changes to multiple java files. After doing so, and saving the files, I ran a file called set_javac.bat (also inherited). Here's a redacted version of that file:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_85

rem set JAR_HOME="D:\Cognos\cognos_version\sdk\java\lib"
set JAR_HOME="D:\code\lib"

set JAVAC=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/javac

set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%/bin
rem Create the Classpath

set CLASSPATH=
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%JAVA_HOME%/lib/tools.jar

rem Compile Java files
```

After running this file, I am then to run build.bat (also inherited - redacted):

```
@echo off

rem Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
rem 
rem IBM Cognos Products: CAMAAA
rem 
rem (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2005, 2012
rem 

rem  Copyright © 2008 Cognos ULC, an IBM Company. All Rights Reserved.
rem  Cognos and the Cognos logo are trademarks of Cognos ULC (formerly Cognos Incorporated).

rem Build Java files in directory TestSample

echo Building TestSample

rem Build the CLASSPATH required to build Java files in the directory TestSample

set _CLASSPATH=D:\code\lib\CAM_AAA_CustomIF.jar;D:\code\adapters;D:\Cognos\cognos_version\webapps\p2pd\WEB-INF\lib\ojdbc6.jar;D:\code\lib\axis.jar;D:\code\lib\jaxrpc.jar

rem Compile Java files
javac -Xlint:unchecked -classpath %_CLASSPATH% -d . *.java

rem Create jar file
jar cfm0 CAM_AAA_TestSample.jar MANIFEST *.class

echo done
```

Both of these .bat files run without error. New .class files are created in the same directory as their .java files. A new CAM_AAA_TestSample.jar file is created also. However, when the .jar file is put in the right location and the Cognos service is restarted and I check the log file, I don't see the changes that I made. Specifically, I have changed log messages from (for example):

```
thisfile: init
```

to...

```
thisfile.java -> init: Entered function
```

But when I open up the log file, I see new messages (date/time stamped) with the old format still. What am I doing wrong?

If you need more details about the setup, please let me know and I'll get you what I can. We use Eclipse to manage the workspace and use "intellisence", but we don't build with it. Any information you can provide is truly appreciated.

Comment: This may be naive, but have you tried navigating to the files outside of eclipse? I have had similar issues with IntelliJ where it does not actually write the changes I've made to disk until I explicitly hit save. Your scripts look like they will generate new class files even if nothing has changed.

Comment: Does this jar exist in more than one place on the class path?  Maybe you're not replacing the one that's actually being used?

Comment: Before posting this question, I did check the files just to make sure. :) As I wrote "New .class files are created in the same directory as their .java files.", I thought "But do the .java files look like those I have in eclipse?" So, I opened them up in Notepad and they were the same. And yes, the batch files do create new .class files even if there are no changes.

Comment: At this time, I don't honestly know, but I don't believe so. When the Sys Admins replace the "working" file with the new one I created, I verify that it has the same timestamp as the one in the directory it was built in. But I'll look around.

Comment: I've had it happen that some class definition appear in two places.  Then the JVM takes the first that it finds.  It could be that the "working" file is not the one that you think it is. Hard to tell from here though. Just a thought.

Comment: @Brick - You may have been on to something. We had copies of the jar file in the wording directory, but they were appended with "_OLD" or "_02082017" or "_COPY" or something similar. However, it seems Cognos was looking for ANYTHING with the TestSample in the file name and it did not guarantee which one was picked. Once we "backed up" the "copies" and left only one *TestSample.jar file in the directory, my changes were seen. If you'd like, post an answer and I'll mark it was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to have a class defined in more than one class file or jar file on your class path. When this happens, the JVM picks one to use - I'm pretty sure that it's the first that it encounters in the order that it has the files listed in the class path.

My guess was that you had a case like this and that you were replacing *a* jar file that contained the old class definition but the JVM was actually using a definition from some other file on your class path.  Looks like from your comments that this was more or less correct.